# error reading pdf file generated using dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I'm trying to generate a table from html to pdf using dompdf, but I'm getting a file corrupted error when I open it on foxit reader or adobe reader, Sumatra can open the file that dompdf generates without problems

```
 <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Course</th>
            </tr>
            <?php   
            foreach($select as $s){     
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $s->strName; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s->strCourse; ?></td>
            </tr>       
            <?php } ?>

 </table>
```

Here's the file which generates the pdf. The output of the code above is just stored into the session, and this file just extract its contents:

```
require_once('../classes/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();


$data = $_SESSION['view'];

ob_start();
?>

<!--css-->


<?php
$subj = $_SESSION['view']['bi'];

echo $subj.'<hr/>';

foreach($data as $d){


        echo $d.'<br/>';

}

$print = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_flush();

$tym = date('g:i s');
$filename = 'print '.$subj. $tym;
$dompdf->load_html($print);

    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename. ".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

How do I determine the error for this one.

Comment: please comment if you need more details. thanks!

Comment: You might try opening the PDF with a text editor. If PHP error display is not disabled some warning can wind up at the top of the PDF source, causing problems for most readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. The solution I came up with was to simply upgrade to [DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 2](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/ReleaseNotes). I tested the generated PDF with Evince (Linux), Acrobat Reader and the native viewer (Mac) and Adobe Reader again on Windows. All work perfectly well.

Updgrading is pretty easy, however for me (as my config options are the same as default), I commented out everything in `dompdf_config.custom.inc.php` and left things at their defaults, which works for most cases.